# HTML Table Words Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's been a while since I've used HTML and CSS, but I need some help. You see, when I try to make a table in HTML and style it in CSS it ends up like this:

http://prntscr.com/mw164x

```css
        #row1 {
            border: 2px;
            border-spacing: 60%;
            border-collapse: none;
            border-color: solid black;
            border-style: solid;
            padding: 23px;
            width: 25px;
            height: 1px;
            background-color: url();
        }
```

```html
<body>


    <table>

        <tr>
            <div id="row1">
                <td>My Account</td>
                <td>Payments/Transfers<td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1. A `tr` cannot contain a `div` as a direct child. Only a `td` (table cell) or `th` (table header) or `tbody`, `thead`. 2. Your div is overlapping your table. Remove the div (opening and closing tag), and make your table like this: `<tr id="row1"> <th>My Account</th> <th>Payments/Transfers<th> </tr>`

Comment: Well thank you, but now the issue is that the border is not showing up??

Answer (score 1):

If you only want a border on the first row:

```css
table {
  /* This makes borders visible, and removes spaces between cells */
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}

thead tr {
  /* This shows a border around the table head */
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>My Account</th>
      <th>Payments / Transfers</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>356</td>
      <td>$35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>432</td>
      <td>$23</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```